# java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, restlet

I'm not entirely sure what is this Restlet error:

```
[INFO] java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
[INFO] Exception Details:
[INFO]   Location:
[INFO]     org/restlet/ext/servlet/internal/ServletWarClient.<init>(Lorg/restlet/Context;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V @95: putfield
[INFO]   Reason:
[INFO]     Type 'org/restlet/ext/servlet/internal/ServletWarClientHelper' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/restlet/engine/ClientHelper'
[INFO]   Current Frame:
[INFO]     bci: @95
[INFO]     flags: { }
[INFO]     locals: { 'org/restlet/ext/servlet/internal/ServletWarClient', 'org/restlet/Context', 'javax/servlet/ServletContext' }
[INFO]     stack: { 'org/restlet/ext/servlet/internal/ServletWarClient', 'org/restlet/ext/servlet/internal/ServletWarClientHelper' }
[INFO]   Bytecode:
[INFO]     0000000: 2a2b 0312 0b12 0d12 0fb8 0015 b600 1b01
[INFO]     0000010: c000 1d03 121f 120d 120f b800 15b7 0022
[INFO]     0000020: 2a03 120d 120d 120f b800 15b6 0026 0312
[INFO]     0000030: 2812 0d12 0fb8 0015 b200 2e03 1230 120d
[INFO]     0000040: 120f b800 15b9 0034 0200 572a bb00 3659
[INFO]     0000050: 2a2c 0312 3812 0d12 0fb8 0015 b700 3bb5
[INFO]     0000060: 003d b1                                
[INFO] 
[INFO]  at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.createWarClient(ServerServlet.java:756)
[INFO]  at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.createComponent(ServerServlet.java:429)
[INFO]  at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.getComponent(ServerServlet.java:840)
[INFO]  at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.createServer(ServerServlet.java:521)
[INFO]  at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.getServer(ServerServlet.java:943)
[INFO]  at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1112)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
[INFO]
```

The complete source I just copied from: https://github.com/xylo04/HelloGaeRestletGradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `org.restlet.gae`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gae</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gae</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gae</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error and the first solution didn't help me.

The issue in my project was that there was another maven dependency which had also used a reslet dependency only with a different version (that is why you get the error "java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack").

The solution is to make them agree on that dependency (my case was easy, the other dependency wasn't in use, it was just there to make my life sad for half a day).

If you do need that dependency, try using the same restlet version as that dependency is using.